# The lexical root of the perfect tense forms differs from the lexical root of the infinitive form

Tags: etymology, morphology, perfect-tense

Do the Latin have any other verbs, whose perfect tense forms base on the lexical root, that differs from the lexical root of the infinitive form (by analogy with the verb *fero > tuli*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ferre* is not the only example, but the phenomenon is quite rare.
Here are the examples that come to mind:

- *ferre* (*tul-*) and prefixed versions
- *esse* (*fu-*) and prefixed versions
- *tollere* (*sustul-*)

Predicting the perfect stem from the present stem is quite hard outside the first conjugation, but they do still generally come from the same origin with some adjustments.
For example, *tang-* and *tetig-* both have the element *tag*, one with a nasal augment and one with reduplication and weakening.

Answer (score 6):

In general, this is called *suppletion*: when some forms of a verb are stolen from a totally different verb. For example, English *to go* has no past-tense forms; the past tense is taken from the unrelated verb *to wend* (as in "wend your way").

In later Latin leading into Romance, for an extreme example, the verb *eō, īre* lost many of its conjugations, replacing them with forms from *ambulāre* "to walk", *vadere* "to advance", and even *esse* "to be"! The choice of which to use isn't consistent even within a tense: compare French *je vais* < *ego vadō* with *nous allons* < *nōs ambulāmus*.

For some more Latin examples:

- *sum, esse, **fuī, futurus***, "be", suppleted with (effectively) *fīō* "become"
- *fīō, fierī, **factus***, "become", suppleted with *faciō* "make" because *esse* stole its perfect stem
- As you mentioned, *ferō, ferre, **tulī, lātus***, "carry", suppleted with *tollō*, "lift"
- *tollō, tollere, **sustulī, sublātus***, "lift", plus a prefix because the original perfect forms were stolen by *ferō*
- *feriō, ferīre, **percussī, percussus***, "hit", suppleted with *percutiō* "beat" (thanks to Hugh for this one)

All the other ones I can think of are compounds from one of these, usually *sum*.

Comment: It is appropriate that the proper term 'suppletion,' resolutely refuses to adopt the suppleted form 'supplementation.'

Answer (score 2):

Also
*ferio, ici (percussi), ictum (percussum)*

Some inceptives as
*adolesco, adolevi.* grow up.

And groups with oblique links to the present stem:
*struo, struxi.*
*torqueo, torsi.* twist
*torreo, torri.* scorch